# Resizing images of related model laravel-admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-admin

I use https://laravel-admin.org/docs/en/README on my site.

I have two models `Post` and `PostImage`.

In the `Post` model in the controller, I added fields that add images to the `PostImage` model, everything works and the images are saved, here is the code:

```
/**
     * Make a form builder.
     *
     * @param int|null $id
     *
     * @return Form
     */
    protected function form($id = null)
    {
        $form = new Form(new Post());

        $form->column(
            1 / 2,
            function (Form $form) use ($id) {
                $form->switch('status', __('Status'));
                $form->number('order', __('Order'))->default(10)->required();
                $form->text('title', __('Title'))->required();
                $form->ckeditor('description', __('Description'))->required();
            }
        );
        $form->column(
            1 / 2,
            function (Form $form) {
                $form->hasMany(
                    'postImages',
                    'Images',
                    function ($form) {
                        if ($form->model()) {
                            $href = admin_url('post-images/' . $form->model()->id . '/edit');
                            $form->html(
                                '<div class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="' . $href . '"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Edit</a></div>'
                            );
                        }
                        $form->image('img_preview', __('Preview image'))->move(PostImage::PATH_PREFIX_PREVIEW)->required();
                    }
                );

        return $form;
    }
```

Now I need to resize the image and resave it, for this I add `$form->saved()` here with the corresponding code, now this is what it looks like:

```
/**
     * Make a form builder.
     *
     * @param int|null $id
     *
     * @return Form
     */
    protected function form($id = null)
    {
        $form = new Form(new Post());

        $form->column(
            1 / 2,
            function (Form $form) use ($id) {
                $form->switch('status', __('Status'));
                $form->number('order', __('Order'))->default(10)->required();
                $form->text('title', __('Title'))->required();
                $form->ckeditor('description', __('Description'))->required();
            }
        );
        $form->column(
            1 / 2,
            function (Form $form) {
                $form->hasMany(
                    'postImages',
                    'Images',
                    function ($form) {
                        if ($form->model()) {
                            $href = admin_url('post-images/' . $form->model()->id . '/edit');
                            $form->html(
                                '<div class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="' . $href . '"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Edit</a></div>'
                            );
                        }
                        $form->image('img_preview', __('Preview image'))->move(PostImage::PATH_PREFIX_PREVIEW)->required();
                    }
                );

                $form->saved(
                    static function ($form) {
                        /**
                         * @var PostImage $postImage
                         * @var Request      $request
                         */
                        $postImage= $form->model();
                        $request = request();
        
                        if ($request->file('img_preview')) {
                            $postImage->copyImg(
                                'img_preview',
                                180,
                                120,
                                $postImage->img_preview,
                                PostImage::PATH_PREFIX_PREVIEW
                            );
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );

        return $form;
    }
```

But it doesn't work, there are no errors. The function itself just doesn't work. Although the code is working, when I use this `$form->saved()` in the `PostImage` model controller, everything works and the image is resized.

There is an assumption that I am trying to store the `PostImage` model inside the `Post` model, but this does not work like that.

How can this be fixed? I would be grateful for any hint..